# Understanding a java log-file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, shutdown-hook

As a beginner technical support, I received a logfile from our client written in Java. The client cannot preview a document. I need some help in order to understand the system messages in the log file in order to explain the issue to the client with simple words.

Here the log file:

```
    2018-10-09 14:05:56,890 INFO [Rendition#0] com.macador.common.management.mbean.MBeanObjectHelper:163 - Registered : 'com.macador.viewer.rendition.local.LocalDocumentService:type=generateImage'
    2018-10-09 14:05:56,890 INFO [Rendition#0] com.macador.common.management.mbean.MBeanObjectHelper:163 - Registered : 'com.macador.viewer.rendition.pdf.jni.JNIPdfRenderer:type=generateImage_width_1800'
    2018-10-09 14:05:56,985 WARN [Grizzly(4)] com.macador.viewer.rendition.document.AsynchronousParsingDocument:299 - No bookmarks provided, returning empty List
    2018-10-09 14:05:57,107 INFO [Rendition#2] com.macador.common.management.mbean.MBeanObjectHelper:163 - Registered : 'com.macador.viewer.rendition.pdf.jni.JNIPdfRenderer:type=generateImage_width_100'
    2018-10-09 14:05:57,306 INFO [Grizzly(2)] com.macador.common.management.mbean.MBeanObjectHelper:163 - Registered : 'com.macador.viewer.rendition.pdf.jni.JNIPdfDocument:type=getPageContents'
    2018-10-09 14:05:57,306 WARN [Grizzly(2)] com.macador.viewer.rendition.pdf.jni.JNIPdfDocument:252 - [PERF] Long time spent getting page for document=b64_I2RlZmF1bHQ=, pageNumber=0 : 651
    2018-10-09 14:05:57,310 WARN [Grizzly(1)] com.macador.viewer.rendition.pdf.jni.JNIPdfDocument:252 - [PERF] Long time spent getting page for document=b64_I2RlZmF1bHQ=, pageNumber=1 : 632
    2018-10-09 14:06:04,620 INFO [Thread-5] com.macador.viewer.rendition.local.LocalDocumentService:253 - Calling Shutdown Hook for LocalDocumentService : cleanup documentMap ...
    2018-10-09 14:06:04,621 INFO [Thread-5] com.macador.viewer.rendition.local.LocalDocumentService:256 - Calling Shutdown Hook for LocalDocumentService : calling System.gc() ...
    2018-10-09 14:06:04,866 INFO [Thread-5] com.macador.viewer.rendition.local.LocalDocumentService:258 - Calling Shutdown Hook for LocalDocumentService : done.
```

Comment: I don't think your company will be happy if their find logs on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant messages are the ones marked as log level: WARN .

`2018-10-09 14:05:56,985 WARN [Grizzly(4)] com.macador.viewer.rendition.document.AsynchronousParsingDocument:299 -`

**No bookmarks provided, returning empty List**

`2018-10-09 14:05:57,306 WARN [Grizzly(2)] com.macador.viewer.rendition.pdf.jni.JNIPdfDocument:252 - [PERF]`

**Long time spent getting page for document**=b64_I2RlZmF1bHQ=, pageNumber=0 : 651

`2018-10-09 14:05:57,310 WARN [Grizzly(1)] com.macador.viewer.rendition.pdf.jni.JNIPdfDocument:252 - [PERF]`

**Long time spent getting page for document**=b64_I2RlZmF1bHQ=, pageNumber=1 : 632

I have highlighted the message in bold. These are plain English and should be easy for you to interpret.